# Elasticsearch head plugin available via public ip

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-virtual-machine, elasticsearch-head

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS running in Azure VM.

I've cloned, built and started elasticsearch-head as posted here - https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head#running-with-built-in-server

After that HEAD seems to be running on http://localhost:9100/ only, but I need it to be available on http://public_ip:9100/ as well.

How can I do so?

Comment: Check the app.js file, it seems to be taking a base URI from configuration, I have not gone through the code base entirely, however, if you could locate the config file, then probably you could change it or if there is no config file, perhaps you can provide one. this.base_uri = this.config.base_uri || this.prefs.get("app-base_uri") || "http://localhost:9200";

Comment: Yep, it seems like app-base_uri in app.js is taken from some config, but can't find relevant config(

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code in your GruntFile:

```
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                port: 9100,
                base: '.',
                keepalive: true
            }
        }
    }
```

with:

```
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                hostname:'<your_host_name>',
                port: 9100,
                base: '.',
                keepalive: true
            }
        }
    }
```

And then re-run your head plugin. For most cloud platforms, the hostname is the private IP for the instance.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost did the tricks - works fine in hostname is "elasticsearch0" - http://prntscr.com/gs85qb but fails if hostname is "elasticsearch0.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com" - http://prntscr.com/gs85yu

Comment: and if I add private ip as a hostname it works, but if I add public ip as a hostname it fails

Comment: I've enabled CORS in elasticsearch config (It looks like this - http://prntscr.com/gs88p8) but it also didn't help

Comment: well, now Head is up and running, I've set local ip in Gruntfile.js , but it cant connect to Elasticsearch cluster - http://prntscr.com/gs9i9f why?

Comment: By default, head plugin tries to connect at localhost:9200. To change this you need to pass an additional query param. You could do this as follows:

<your_head_plugin_url>?base_uri=<your_elasticsearch_url>

Comment: even if I run Head on the same machine with elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes. This is because you are trying to access Elasticsearch from your browser. And your browser doesn't know which address to point the head plugin to. 
However, if you run Elasticsearch on your local system, head plugin should work right away since it tries to access localhost:9200 by default.

Comment: No. Put it in your browser's address.
It would look something like this: 13.93.127.116:9100?base_uri=<your_elasticsearch_url>

Comment: I've tried http://176.100.16.25:9100?base_uri=13.93.109.241:9200/ where 176.100.16.25 is my laptop's IP and 13.93.109.241is my elasticsearch server IP on which HEAD is running. And it doesn't work(

Comment: Ok. Could you please give me the public IP of both the systems: 1. Where your head plugin is  running 2. Where your elasticsearch is deployed?

Comment: Sure, both are running on 13.93.109.241 , Elasticsearch port is 9200, HEAD port is 9100 - http://prntscr.com/gtmcs6

Comment: This would be your URL then:
13.93.109.241:9100?base_uri=13.93.109.241:9200

Comment: You need to put the link I sent as the browser address, not the head plugin address.

Comment: Check if your 9200 port for the instance is open to your IP.

Comment: It is open - http://prntscr.com/gu0tda and I even can work thought the Sense plugin - http://prntscr.com/gu0tl0

Comment: Did you enable CORS? Also, hope you restarted the service after updating it?

Comment: yep, CORS is enabled - http://prntscr.com/gu6j0b and service was restarted after that

Comment: Not sure then. Try removing:
http.cors.allow-headers: Authorization

If that doesn't work too, then I am out of ideas here. I would just do a fresh setup and try to backtrack what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry, mate. Can't really think of anything that can go wrong then without actually looking at the system.

Comment: yep, that's really wired, will try set everything from scratch

Comment: All the best, mate.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I'll update this post when I find the solution